# Remix deploy: pass account password

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

I use my web3 as account provider. When I deploy it asks for password, I can see that in clef logs

```
## Account password

Please enter the password for account 0x1554ce5a208c80D6087d73296E65405002cd640e
```

How can I force Remix IDE to pass this password?

Comment: Are you using MetaMask?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg geth